# Twitter StreamingClient 2 rules

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

I'm running this file with 1 rule:

```py
value1 = ('from:{user} -is:retweet').format(user)
value2 = ('to:{user} is:reply').format(user)

class CustomStream(StreamingClient):
    def on_connect(self):
        print("Connected!")
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        try:
            print(f"{tweet.id} {tweet.created_at} ({tweet.author_id}): {tweet.text}")
            print("-" * 50)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            sys.stderr.write('Error on_data: {}\n'.format(e))
            time.sleep(5)
        return True

stream = CustomStream(bearer_token=bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
previousRules = stream.get_rules().data
if previousRules:
    stream.delete_rules(previousRules)
rule1 = StreamRule(value=value1)
# rule2 = StreamRule(value=value2)
stream.add_rules(rule1)
stream.filter(tweet_fields=["created_at", "author_id"],expansions=["author_id"])
```

Is it possible to run a stream by two rules at the same time? maybe possible to do multiprocessing, but i dont know how.Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what about `stream.filter(tweet_fields=["created_at", "author_id"],expansions=["author_id"],threaded=True)`